# Probability that Random Harmonic Type Series Converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Recently I have come across a variety of truly wonderful results that deal with series that look like harmonic series:

> All of the series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+1/n}}, \ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(n)|}{n}, \ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2 - \epsilon + \sin(n)}}, \ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + |\sin(n)|}}   $$ diverge.

The proof for the latter three mostly hinges on the fact that the fractional parts of $\{\sin(n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are equidistributed in the unit interval.

This leads me to ask the following question:

> Let $u_i \sim Unif([0,1])$. What is the probability that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+ u_n}}$$ diverges ?

Similarly, we can ask an analogue question where $u_i$ are drawn from an arbitrary distribution $X$. I do not much knowledge in this area so any helpful comments and directions are welcomed.

Comment: Can you attach the link showing those sums diverge please?

Comment: @mathworker21 The very first one is because $1/n^{1+1/n} > 1/(2n)$. The second one is because either $|sin(n)|$ or $|sin(n+1)|$ is greater than some constant $C$. (I found it in the book Putnam and Beyond). The third one follows from the fact that $\sin(n)$ is dense mod $1$. The fourth one is a problem from the American Mathematical Monthly. (It is somewhere on this site also).

Comment: The fourth one is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270064/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n1-sinn-conve

Comment: To make sense of the question: should $u_i$ be $u_n$, we $(u_n)_n$ a sequence of *independent* r.v.s"?

Comment: @ClementC. Yes sorry, it is fixed now.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal, thanks! I assume for the third one, you mean $\sin(n)$ is uniformly distributed mod $1$. I don't see how that gets you what you want though. For example, there are divergent series but when you take a sum over a subset of the natural numbers with positive density, you get a convergent series.

Comment: @mathworker21: Do you have any examples of that ? For the third series, since $2-\epsilon$ is fixed, you can copy the proof from problem 5 here: http://www.math.illinois.edu/~ajh/putnam/problems/mock07-1sol.pdf

Comment: @SandeepSilwal, well there are trivial examples such as $\sum a_n$ where $a_n$ is $0$ for even $n$ and $1$ for odd $n$. A nontrivial example follows from here 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206466/construct-series

But I am curious if $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1+u_n}}$ converges whenever $u_n$ is a u.d. sequence mod $1$. The proof you showed seems to use properties of $\sin$ specifically.

Comment: @mathworker21: Ah yes. Herm, Im not really sure for a general u.d. sequence. I think the answer should be yes but I can't think of an argument that would work off the top of my head.

Comment: One thing I want to point out is that $\{\sin n\}$ is not equidistributed. $\{e^{in}\}$ is equidistributed, not the $\{\sin n\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The random variable $\displaystyle {1\over n^{1+u_n}}$ has mean value $\int_0^1 {1\over n^{1+u}}\,du\approx {1\over n\log(n)}$. Since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty {1\over n\log(n)}=\infty$ the  random sum also diverges to infinity, with probability one. This follows, for example, from [Kolmogorov's three series theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_three-series_theorem)

In the three series theorem, the random series either converges with probability 1, or diverges with probability 1. And since the summands are positive, your series must diverge to $+\infty$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! That is exactly the type of theorem that I was looking for. To be more clear, this violates the second condition of the theorem right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov's_three-series_theorem

This gives many necessary conditions for it to converge almost surely. One condition is violated. How do you know it diverges almost surely?

Comment: @mathworker21 The random sum converges if and only if *all three* conditions hold for all positive $A$. We can take $A=2$ here and $X_n=Y_n={1\over n^{1+u_n}}.$

Comment: You don't seem to understand the flaw in logic I am pointing out. It converges almost surely iff all 3 conditions hold. One condition was violated. Therefore, it's not the case that it converges almost surely. HOWEVER, you said it diverges almost surely. How did you make that leap?

Comment: There's another result of Kolmogorov, known as his "zero-one law" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law ), that is relevant here.  Essentially you can think of it as saying that if you have an event determined by a sequence of independent variables such that the event is independent of the behavior of any finite subset of those variables, then the event must have probability $0$ or $1$.  It applies here since changing a finite number of terms in a sequence doesn't affect convergence or divergence.

Comment: @KevinCostello Thanks for that comment. I should have made that clearer in my post.